# JPA search in map<String, String>

Tags: string, search, jpa, join, dictionary

i'm having troubles with JPA.. I try to search in a map a certain string occurence.

here is my object's property :

```
@ElementCollection(fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyColumn(name="locale") 
@Column(name="value")
private Map<Locale, String> localized = new HashMap<Locale, String>();
```

and i'm trying to search one value of the localized map like this :

```
SELECT count(f) FROM Faq f  WHERE f.answer.localized like :question.
```

i tried using the elements(f.answer.localized) but it does not work .. 
is there any other solution than creating a "LocalizedObject" on which i could use an InnerJoin ?

edit : I want to search for an occurrence, so if the map is {[en_US : "hi Joe", en_UK : "big up"]} , the search field could be "up".
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

JPQL includes the Key and Value operators to allow you specify which part of the map you wish to use in your query.  For example here you might use:

```
"SELECT count(f) FROM Faq f join f.answer.localized localized WHERE VALUE(localized) like :question"
```